# Maximum number of vertices of a hypercube that can be visited with a polygonal chain of given size

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, graph-theory, optimization

Which is the maximum number of vertices of a hypercube (for sake of clarity, let us consider the $(n + 3)$-dimensional hypercube $\{(0, 1) \times (0, 1) \times \dots \times (0, 1)\}$) that can be visited by using a polygonal chain of size $n$?

We know that no hypecube has $3$ collinear points, thus our sequence starts at $2$, for $n = 1$. 
On the other hand, we can join the $6$ vertices $(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$, $(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)$, $(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)$, $(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$, $(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$, and $(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ of the $7$-dimensional hypercube $\{(0, 1) \times (0, 1) \times (0, 1) \times (0, 1) \times (0, 1) \times (0, 1) \times (0, 1)\}$ with $P(4)$, a polygonal chain of size $4$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}^7$, which is defined as $(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$-$(2, -1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)$-$(0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$-$\left(\frac{3}{2}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0\right)$-$(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$.

My conjecture is that any optimal polygonal chain has a link-legth of $\left\lfloor \frac{4}{3} \cdot (n + 2) \right\rfloor - 2$ (i.e., we can join $2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, \dots$) new vertices as $n$ grows). 
Is it possible to prove or disprove this?

Moreover, if the above holds for every positive integer $n$, I conjecture that it is possible to cover any $k$-dimensional hypercube by using a polygonal chain of size $3 \cdot 2^{k-2}$.

Comment: This is an interesting question . Would you mind sharing what the origin of this question is?

Comment: Thank you, the original source is my paper entitled "General uncrossing covering paths inside the Axis-Aligned Bounding Box", https://ejournal2.undip.ac.id/index.php/jfma/article/download/12053/6717
It provides also some optimal covering paths, trails, circuits, and cycles for the 3D case (polygonal chains of size 6). From the P(4) which I've given above (I've found it in a a couple of minutes) you can also infer that a solution for the tesseract is P(12) and we have no reason to assume that the average number of vertices reached will drop from R^5 and above.

Comment: I thought that the vertices of a seven-dimensional cube are sequences of $0$ and $1$ of length $7$. But there are other numbers in your polygonal chain example for $P(4)$. Can you please clarify the definitions or explain them in more detail.

Comment: I meant. Let P(4) be the size 4 polygonal chain in R^7 defined as P(4) := (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)-(2, -1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)-(0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)-(3/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)-(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0). It follows that P(4) visits the 6 vertices (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), and (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) of the 7-dimensional hypercube {(0, 1) x (0, 1) x (0, 1) x (0, 1) x (0, 1) x (0, 1) x (0, 1)}.

Comment: @Marco thanks. It seems to me that this answer of yours makes sense to put in your question. I now understand that the edges of a polygonal chain do not necessarily coincide with the edges of our hypercube.

Yes, this is indeed an interesting problem.

Comment: @kabenyuk. Clarifying explanation added to the original post.

Comment: Just so I understand, what is the polygonal chain of length $6$ that covers the ordinary cube?

Comment: @Brian, you can find several polygonal chains of length 6 that covers the ordinary cube (even circuits with all their links belonging to the same Euclidean lenght class) in my paper "General uncrossing covering paths inside the Axis-Aligned Bounding Box" ( https://doi.org/10.14710/jfma.v4i2.12053 ), see Figures 7--9, the polygonal chains are given explicitly there. Otherwise, just consider the uncrossing covering path (1,0,0)-(0,0,0)-(2,2,2)-(1/2,-1,1/2)-(-1/2,1,3/2)-(1,1,0)-(1,1,0).

Comment: Have you considered putting this question on Math.OF?

Comment: Do you have the constraint that each edge of the polygonal chain has to visit at least one vertice of the cube? Otherwise it is easy to visit 2, 0, 2, 0, 2... vertices, which is nearly as good as 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2...

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni, there is no such constraint, but (as you correctly noted), we cannot improve the total numer of visited vertices with such a sequence (i.e., 2, 0, 2, 0, 2,... since the total is always equal to - or below than -  2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2,...). The only thing we know for sure is that it is not possible to visit all the vertices of a cube with a covering trail of size 5, but I am not able to prove that 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2,... holds for a tesseract and above. It is just a conjecture I strongly believe in.

Comment: P.S. As expected, I've just found a polygonal chain of size 12 taht visits all the vertices of the tesseract. I've also posted two related conjectures of mine on MathOverflow... in order to prove everything, we just need to find which is maximum (total) number of vertices that can be visited with a polygonal chain of size 3 and 6.

Comment: Just to say that we have fully solved this problem and also constructively proved that any optimal polygonal chain containing all the points of the set $H(2,k):=\{\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \times \dots \times \{0,1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ has exactly $3 \cdot 2^{k-2}$ links. A preprint will be released soon with a full proof. Thanks to everybody for having joined this challenge!

Answer (score 0):

Happy to announce that both my old conjectures stated in the present thread were right. Here is our formal proof that the minimum-link covering trails (and also cycles) for the $2^k$ vertices of any $k$-cube, such that $k > 1$, have (exactly) $3 \cdot 2^{k-2}$ links: https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.11216

Any comments are welcome.